# Employee Schedules for the next 2 weeks

Tags: mysql

Im currently working on a couple of MySQL events to publish employee schedules for the next 14 days.

Every employee has a set schedule every day. I currently have a table that contains the scheudles but instead of having the date, it has the day name. Here is an example of the table:

```
| ID |  EmpID   |   LOB  |    DOW    |   event  | StartAt   |    EndAt |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  |Z.Mora3847|  FNOL  |   Monday  |   Shift  |   9:00    |   17:30  |
| 2  |Z.Mora3847|  FNOL  |   Tuesday |   Shift  |   9:00    |   17:30  |
| 3  |Z.Mora3847|  FNOL  |  Wednesday|   Shift  |   9:00    |   17:30  |
```

I have to find a way to generate the next 2 week schedules for each employee based on the day of the week from this table and store it into a similar table where instead of having the column "dow" we have a column called "date" and it must contain the future date matching the dayname from the first table.

If I try this, it returns me the expected value for one day:

```
select SB.EmpID, SB.lob, dow, date_add(curdate(),interval 1 day) as Date, SB.StartAt, SB.EndAt from SandBox.ScheduleBase as SB where dayname(date_add(curdate(), interval 1 day)) = dow
```

and this is the output:

```
| ID |  EmpID   | LOB  |  DOW      |  Date      | StartAt   |    EndAt |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  |Z.Mora3847|FNOL  | Saturday  | 2021-04-17 |   9:00    |   17:30  |
```

And I want to be able to do this for the next 14 days.

Im using 5.5.68-MariaDB

I hope you guys can help me with this one.

Comment: What did you try ?  Maybe this helps `select now(), dayname(now());` will output todays date, and todays dayname ("Friday").

Comment: This is what I tried and it work for one date:

'select SB.EmpID, SB.lob, date_add(curdate(),interval 1 day), SB.event, SB.StartAt, SB.EndAt from SandBox.ScheduleBase as SB
where dayname(curdate()) = dow'

But how do I go for getting the next 14 days?

Comment: Please add that info to your question (using the [edit] functionality)

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using? Can you add the output of this to the question: `SELECT @@VERSION;`?

Comment: I just updated the question, thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to replace the `DOW` column for the actual date (let's say we name it `EventDate`); you can calculate the day of week using [`DAYOFWEEK()` function](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-dayofweek-function.php):

```sql
SELECT DAYOFWEEK(EventDate);
```

This function returns `1` for Sunday, `2` for Monday, and so on (until `7` for Saturday). If week starts on Monday, and you need the following two working weeks (e.g., week ending on Sunday), thanks to the help [from this post](http://www.gizmola.com/blog/feeds/archives/99-Finding-Next-Monday-using-MySQL-Dates.html), we can get the next Monday as:

```sql
SELECT DATE_ADD(EventDate, INTERVAL (9 - IF(DAYOFWEEK(EventDate)=1, 8, DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()))) DAY);
```

We can create a function for that, to ease the writing of our query:

```sql
-- Please check this in a database for real, I'm not sure if syntax is correct
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION NEXTMONDAY(TargetDate DATE)
RETURNS DATE DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE ResultDate DATE;
  SELECT DATE_ADD(TargetDate, INTERVAL (9 - IF(DAYOFWEEK(TargetDate)=1, 8, DAYOFWEEK(TargetDate))) DAY) INTO ResultDate;
  RETURN ResultDate;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Now, by using this function, we can create our query as:

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM ScheduleTable
  WHERE EmpId = '__employee id here__'
    AND EventDate BETWEEN NEXTMONDAY(CURDATE()) AND ADDDATE(NEXTMONDAY(CURDATE()), INTERVAL 13 DAY)
```

***Use 13 days instead of 14 to make the end day (which is inclusive) to be Sunday***

Sorry for the long explanation, I hope it helps. And if there is something you can not understad, let me know; as my mother tongue is not English I may commit mistakes.

---

**EDIT 1 (extending the answer):** To have the actual *name* of the day of the week (rather than the number), you have the built-in function `DAYNAME`. It receives a `DATE` and returns a `VARCHAR` containing the name of the week day. If you have the `EventDate` column, you can do `DAYNAME(EventDate)` to get the name of the week day.

Comment: This solution seems to be OK. But you missed one thing the field `EventDate` is not available ...

Comment: I know, that's why I told him at the very beginning to replace the column `DOW` for the column `EventDate` so the whole solution makes sense. Of course, this won't work with recurrent events but makes sure to respect the two next weeks he asked for.

Comment: But there is no way to calculate the EventDate from the DayOfWeek. the other way from Eventdate calculating the DayOfWeek is possible.

Answer (score 0):

To expand the solution from SonicArg:

If you do:

```
with recursive cte(x) as (
  select 0 as x 
  union all 
  select x+1 from cte where x<13) 
select * from cte;
```

You will get 14 numbers from 0 to 13.

and this:

```
with recursive cte(x) as (
  select 0 as x 
  union all 
  select x+1 from cte where x<13) 
SELECT DATE_ADD(NEXTMONDAY(NOW()),INTERVAL cte.x DAY)
FROM cte;
```

will show you all the dates from next monday ('2021-04-19') until sunday ('2021-05-02').

If you combine this with the query from `SonicARG` you will get the desrired results.

I will leave this to you, succes with this!